# Weird difference in behaviour in Developer Story

Tags: bug, developer-story

Noticed that all the "Add a new item" options have the default tooltip besides the "milestone".

So just thought I'd report it.

#### on Windows

`Windows 10`
`Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)`

[image]

#### on OS X

`OS X El Capitan`
`Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)`

[image]

Comment: Try javascript. It is not scary/bad as you think.

Comment: @Shyju I'm not sure if that's what you meant, but that's the placeholder text stackoverflow puts there... I do work with js

Comment: They all have the white tooltip (Firefox 48), which browser and version?

Comment: @cat added info on where this happened to me

Comment: @Thatkookooguy being a stickler, but I'm guessing your operating system is "Windows", not "Widows" ;)

Comment: Also confirm this happens to me in Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Opera on Windows 10... no surprise there I guess

Comment: + IE11 on Win 7. Seems that the 'Milestone' button is the only one with a special tooltip: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkmMt.png